# How fix error "Cannot write struct type 'optional_description_elements' with no child field to Parquet. Consider adding a dummy child field"

Tags: pandas, airflow

I have several dags in which I have an error with passing dataframe between tasks. I will give an example of one of them.

```
def ozon_items():

    @task.external_python(python='/usr/local/airflow/venv_main/bin/python')
    def get_ozon_items():
        from src.transform import OzonTables
        # Request api method and transform. Return DataFrame
        return OzonTables().items()

    @task.external_python(python='/usr/local/airflow/venv_main/bin/python')
    def update_ozon_items(data):
        from src.databases.DatabaseWorker import DatabaseWorker
        from src.databases.markets.ozon_schema import OzonItems

        db = DatabaseWorker(host='host.docker.internal', port=5431)

        with db.session() as session:
            session.upsert(
                OzonItems,
                data,
                on_conflict='do_update',
                deletable=True
            )
    update_ozon_items(get_ozon_items())
```

Previously, I had pandas 2.0 installed, and the “items” method returned Dict. This Dict passed between tasks without any problems. I recently moved the conversion logic from DataFrame to dict in the "upsert" method. Thus, between tasks I need to pass a DataFrame. I have now updated pandas to 2.2.0 and installed pyarrow. Note that there are no empty rows or columns in the dataframe.

Here's the full traceback of the error:

```
> {process_utils.py:186} INFO - Output:
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:50.368 | INFO     | src.transform.ozon:items:24 - Ozon items dataframe transformation
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:50.368 | INFO     | src.api.base_api:request:85 - Request data using method: /v2/product/list
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:51.492 | SUCCESS  | src.api.base_api:request:124 - Request is succesful
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:51.494 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items:133 - Get items list. Total items: 246
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:51.497 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items_info:178 - Items list is not given. All items set by default
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:51.497 | INFO     | src.api.base_api:request:85 - Request data using method: /v2/product/info/list
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:54.947 | SUCCESS  | src.api.base_api:request:124 - Request is succesful
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:54.954 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items_info:185 - Get items info list
> {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2024-02-14 07:02:55.001 | SUCCESS  | src.transform.ozon:items:87 - Dataframe conversion successful
> {python.py:201} INFO - Done. Returned value was:             id  ...                                    link
0      7169458  ...   http.
1      7169459  ...   http.
2      7169460  ...   http.
3      7169461  ...   http.
4      7169462  ...   http.
> ..         ...  ...               ...
241  870801469  ...  http.
242  870801527  ...  http.
243  870801550  ...  http.
244  870815261  ...  http.
245  870849478  ...  http.
[246 rows x 25 columns]
> {taskinstance.py:2699} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 440, in _execute_task
task_instance.xcom_push(key=XCOM_RETURN_KEY, value=xcom_value, session=session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2981, in xcom_push
XCom.set(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 247, in set
value = cls.serialize_value(
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 662, in serialize_value
return json.dumps(value, cls=XComEncoder).encode("UTF-8")
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 104, in encode
return super().encode(o)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 91, in default
return serialize(o)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/serialization/serde.py", line 145, in serialize
data, classname, version, is_serialized = _serializers[qn].serialize(o)
>                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/serialization/serializers/pandas.py", line 51, in serialize
pq.write_table(table, buf, compression="snappy")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py", line 3071, in write_table
with ParquetWriter(
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py", line 990, in __init__
self.writer = _parquet.ParquetWriter(
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1753, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetWriter.__cinit__
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 121, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Cannot write struct type 'optional_description_elements' with no child field to Parquet. Consider adding a dummy child field.
```

**What am I doing wrong and how can this be solved?**

I tried changing the Pandas version to 2.0. Also some other dags are working fine.

ps. I am attaching a [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rett-oo/test/main/itemst.csv) with which I am having problems.

Comment: This error seems to mean that pyArrow can't infer the type of column `optional_description_elements`. You say that none of the rows or columns are empty, but is it possible that this column contains only empty tuples or dictionaries? Can you post a sample of the dataframe? Giving the schema explicitly might help.

Comment: Yes, one of the columns has some empty list . Yes of course, I updated my question.